# How to enable/disable multiple rows delete button of Material Ui data table

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Using Material UI datatable which has everything searching , pagination and multiple rows delete option. Refer from https://openbase.com/js/mui-datatables/documentation (cannot copy paste sample code from client machine)

I need to restrict delete button access based on delete permission user has,

I am new to React and Material UI, need suggestion on how to enable/disable delete button shown up when we select multiple rows.

Comment: You can make your own custom component for toolbar. For button you should use IconButton and add props "disabled={yourCondition}". They explain the customization on documentation (Custom Components section).

Comment: Then will have manage everything by ourselves, which rows are selected for delete and everything when user has permission to delete rows

Answer (score 1):

Got example from material ui code it self which help me to have control on delete icon in header when user selects multiple rows.

https://github.com/gregnb/mui-datatables/blob/master/examples/customize-toolbarselect/CustomToolbarSelect.js

Answer (score 0):

For enable/disable row select

```
const options = {
       selectableRows: "none",
       // selectableRows: "single",
       // selectableRows: 'multiple',
      }
```

For row delete /hide /remove icon from top

```
customToolbarSelect: () => {},
```